# PostgreSQL 9.5: Creating foreign key across database using Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW)

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I want to create foreign key in the current database table by referring other database table.

So i have decided to go with FDW.

I have done the following steps:

**Step 1**: Created extension

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

**Step 2**: Created foreign server

```
CREATE SERVER foreign_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', port '5432', dbname 'testing');

    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'password');
```

**Step 3**: Created foreign table

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE fgn_tbl_calculator 
(
  value1 integer,
  value2 integer,
  sum integer,
  sub integer,
  div integer,
  mul integer
)
SERVER foreign_server
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'calculator');
```

**Step 4**: Creating table with foreign key

```
create table calculator_copy
(
  value1 integer,
  value2 integer,
  sum integer,
  sub integer,
  div integer,
  mul integer,
  primary key (value1),
  foreign key (value1) references fgn_tbl_calculator(value1)
);
```

But stuck with an error:

```
 ERROR:  referenced relation "fgn_tbl_calculator" is not a table
```

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Do we have any possible solution for this problem in other way?

Comment: The *solution* is: don't rely on the stability of *remote* foreign keys.

Comment: If you really need to maintain integrity against remote database you can think about using logical replication to sync given remote foreign table to your local database and then use standard local constraint. But this is very maximalistic solution...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what about a trigger `before insert` that checks the validity of the wanna-be-foreign-key and aborts the insertion if there's no proper key on the remote table? I don't know how to implement the abortion part